# Conditional compilation of Angular app

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to simulate the Angular Tour of Heroes using Webpack and have it work both in browser and Electron. I'd like to conditional create the HeroService class with direct REST requests for the browser, and use IPC to have the main process do it when using Electron. I'm still pretty new to Typescript, so I'm not sure if it's event possible. `TARGET` is a config file variables that determines whether the webpack target should be `web` or `electron-renderer`. I can't seem to get `awesome-typescript-loader` to only conditionally execute the `let ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer`. It works when I set target to be `electron-renderer` and can use it in Electron, but of course then the node integrations are included so I get uses with require when trying to run it in a browser. I've tried the service being a class and an object, but no luck. Here's an example.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Headers, Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Hero} from './hero';
import axios from 'axios';
import {DB_HOST, DB_PORT, API_URL, TARGET} from '../../config/';
const heroesUrl = `http://${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${API_URL}`;

type HeroServiceType = {
  getHeroes: () => Promise<Hero[]>,
  getHero: (id: number) => Promise<Hero>,
  delete: (id: number) => Promise<void>,
  create: (name: string) => Promise<Hero>,
  update: (hero: Hero) => Promise<Hero>
}

let ipc: typeof ipcRenderer;

let HeroService: HeroServiceType;

if (TARGET === 'web') {
  HeroService = {
    getHeroes: () => {
      return axios.get(heroesUrl)
      .then(response => response.data)
      .catch(err => handleError(err));
    },

    getHero: (id) => {
      return axios.get(`${heroesUrl}/${id}`)
      .then(response => response.data[0])
      .catch(err => handleError(err));
    },

    delete: (id) => {
      return axios.delete(`${heroesUrl}/${id}`)
      .then(() => null)
      .catch(err => handleError(err));
    },

    create: (name) => {
      return axios.post(
        heroesUrl,
        JSON.stringify({name}),
        {
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        }
      )
      .then(response => response.data)
      .catch(err => handleError(err));
    },

    update: (hero) => {
      return axios.put(
        `${heroesUrl}/${hero.id}`,
        JSON.stringify(hero),
        {
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        }
      )
      .then(() => hero)
      .catch(err => handleError(err));
    }
  };
}

else {
  let ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

  const handleIPC = function(method: string, query: object): Promise<any> {
    ipc.send(method, query);
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      ipc.once(method, (event, args) => {
        if (args.err) handleError(args.err);
        else if (args.data) resolve(args.data);
        else resolve();
      });
    });
  }

  HeroService = {
    getHeroes: function() {
      return handleIPC('getAll', {});
    },

    getHero: function(id) {
      return handleIPC('get', {id});
    },

    delete: function(id) {
      return handleIPC('delete', {id});
    },

    create: function(name) {
      return handleIPC('create', {name});
    },

    update: function(hero) {
      return handleIPC('update', {hero});
    }
  };
}

function handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
  console.error('An error occurred', error);
  return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
}

export {HeroService, HeroServiceType};
```

I've tried several things. The current example based off of [this post](http://ideasintosoftware.com/typescript-conditional-imports/). Any help or suggestions about alternative is much appreciated

Here it is as a Class

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Hero} from './hero';
import {TARGET} from '../../config';
import axios from 'axios';
import {ipcRenderer} from 'electron';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
  private heroesUrl = 'http://localhost:8081/api/heroes';

  getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    if (TARGET === 'web') {
      return axios.get(this.heroesUrl)
      .then(response => response.data as Hero[])
      .catch(this.handleError);
    }
    else {
      return this.handleIPC('getAll', {});
    }
  }

  getHero(id: number): Promise<Hero> {
    const url = `${this.heroesUrl}/${id}`;
    if (TARGET === 'web') {
      return axios.get(url)
      .then(response => response.data as Hero)
      .catch(this.handleError);
    }
    else {
      return this.handleIPC('get', {id});
    }
  }

  delete(id: number): Promise<void> {
    const url = `${this.heroesUrl}/${id}`;
    if (TARGET === 'web') {
      return axios.delete(url)
      .then(() => null)
      .catch(this.handleError);
    }
    else {
      this.handleIPC('delete', {id});
    }
  }

  create(name: string): Promise<any> {
    if (TARGET === 'web') {
      return axios.post(
        this.heroesUrl,
        JSON.stringify({name}),
        {
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        }
      )
      .then(response => response.data as Hero)
      .catch(this.handleError);
    }
    else {
      return this.handleIPC('create', {name});
    }
  }

  update(hero: Hero): Promise<any> {
    const url = `${this.heroesUrl}/${hero.id}`;
    if (TARGET === 'web') {
      return axios.put(
        url,
        JSON.stringify(hero),
        {
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        }
      )
      .then(() => hero)
      .catch(this.handleError);
    }
    else {
      return this.handleIPC('update', {hero});
    }
  }

  private handleIPC(method: string, query: object) {
    ipcRenderer.send(method, query);
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      ipcRenderer.once(method, (event, args) => {
        if (args.err) this.handleError(args.err);
        else if (args.data) resolve(args.data);
        else resolve();
      });
    });
  }

  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.log('An error occured', error);
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
}
```